# Should I turn off Dynamic Topology if I have a huge number of verts?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

So, I'm making quite a big mesh and at some point I've reached 1.5-2 million verts. This, obviously, slowed down Blender and it's near impossible to work. Is it ok if I turn off Dyntopo? If so, how do I make sure that the part of the mesh I'm working on is at enough high detail level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets be clear:  If a feature isn't working, don't use it.  But I'll also provide an alternate perspective.

Z-Brush only recently got its Dynatopo equivalent: Sculptris mode. The workflow for Z-Brush, which has been the industry standard for years, is to make a lowpoly base mesh and sub-divide it until there is enough density of vertices to keep the detail.  The artist usually is working with a mesh that is at least 3 million polys at this point.

What I'm trying to say is: it is ok if you are starting with a high vertex count and work from there, it's an established pro-workflow.  It is a shame Blender isn't able to handle  larger poly counts right now, but that is out of our control.

Remember that while in Dynatopo, the size of your brush will affect the vertex density.  This means you can remove verts by making your brush larger.  You can reduce parts of the mesh that don't need the detail so you can redirect that budget for parts that do.

Comment: The problem is: I'm done with the main shape of the mesh, I just need to work on the anatomy here and there and then add some higher-level details. So I'm just trying to find a way to make my mesh dense enough to do that without dyntopo. That shouldn't be much work, since I can use a material paint program to add the tiny details more efficient. I haven't even booled the whole thing together. I've seperated the limbs from the main shape, but I've recently booled the head with the body.